# Dev-C++ - [Build Error] [main.o] Error 1

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, dev-c++

Im running into big trouble with my compiler Dev-C++, every time i compile any project, whether it is 1 im working on, or a completely fresh 1 I get the same error every single time, I have been on the bloodshed forums and IRC channel but Im not getting anywhere with it... at the moment and every project I try to compile gives the same error...

```
C:\Dev-Cpp\MY_Project\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [main.o] Error 1
```

**Compiler log**

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Dev-Cpp\MY_Project\Makefile.win"
Executing make...
make.exe -f "C:\Dev-Cpp\MY_Project\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -D__DEBUG__ -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include" -pg -g3

The system cannot find the path specified.

make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

Comment: Don't use Dev-C++? Other than that, I guess check that all the paths in the console output are valid. But really, don't use Dev-C++.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I have checked all of the paths and they all exist...and also it happens when I compile a project from scratch O_x , whats wrong with dev-c++ :?

Comment: Agree with Seth. Use something like [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) or the free version of Visual Studio. Dev-C++ is no longer maintained (it hasn't been since years) and the alternatives mentioned are much much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/37630)? Specifically the first post on [this page](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/37630/page5).

Comment: thats me and non of solutions works , it seems i must give up with dev-c++ , some solutions works for other peoples with same problem but not me , it's annoying this problem happens due to many issues and all u can get from compiler log is same error

Comment: @Synxmax don't worry, it's **way** better. You'll love it.

Answer (score 4):

What is your OS? I think Bloodshed version of the program have some problems with Win8. However you can download [Orwell version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Setup%20Releases/Dev-Cpp%205.3.0.3%20TDM-GCC%20x64%204.6.1%20Setup.exe/download). It runs smoothly.

Comment: thanks for answer but i asked this almost 3 years ago , and i give up using dev-c++ since